# JavaScript - Dynamic Script tag causing "unexpected token illegal"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, json-ld

I'm getting an error dynamically generating this script tag.  It doesn't seem to like the opening bracket.  Can anyone help?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  (function(callback){
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'application/ld+json');

    s.text = '{
      "@@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@@type": "Person",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "jobTitle": "Graduate research assistant",
      "affiliation": "University of Dreams",
      "additionalName": "Johnny",
      "url": "http://www.example.com",
      "address": {
        "@@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "1234 Peach Drive",
        "addressLocality": "Wonderland",
        "addressRegion": "Georgia"
      }
    }';
    s.onload = callback;
    document.body.appendChild(s);
  })();

})



</script>
```

Comment: Don't use the apostrophe in `s.text`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript does not allow multi-line string literals, so the `s.text = '` lines are invalid syntax.

If you output pure JSON to your script instead, then you can do this to make it into a string:

```
s.text = JSON.stringify({
  "@@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@@type": "Person",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "jobTitle": "Graduate research assistant",
  "affiliation": "University of Dreams",
  "additionalName": "Johnny",
  "url": "http://www.example.com",
  "address": {
    "@@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "1234 Peach Drive",
    "addressLocality": "Wonderland",
    "addressRegion": "Georgia"
  }
});
```

Comment: What would be the best way to accomplish generating a dynamic script tag filled with JSON content?

Comment: It depends on how you're generating the dynamic script. In most languages, it's a matter of encoding. On the server, convert your object to JSON, then JSON-encode the JSON string (if that makes sense). Then you'll have a JavaScript-compatible _string_ that contains _JSON_. Or don't put it in a string at all. Output the JSON directly to the script, then do `JSON.stringify` if you need.

Comment: Added comment to clarify what I mean by the latter.